# Does a polynomial with real coeffients have a root greater than $1$ iff the sum of its coefficients are greater than $0$?

Tags: polynomials

Take a polynomial $p$ with real coefficients.

$$p(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k$$

[It's](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326658/conclusion-about-zeros-of-a-polynomial-when-sum-of-its-coefficients-is-zero) "[well-known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1360115/factoring-trick-adding-up-coefficients)" that $1$ is a root if and only if the sum of the coefficients is $0$. $$p(1) = 0 \iff\sum_{k=0}^n a_k = 0$$

Instead, take the case where the sum of the coefficients is positive. Does this this imply that there is real root greater than $1$?

$$ \sum_{k=0}^n a_k > 0 \Rightarrow \exists x_0 > 1 \text{ such that } p(x_0) = 0 $$

I believe this is true, and I expect it's also a fairly standard/well-known result. But I haven't been able to find a reference.

The result where the coefficients sum to zero is apparently a straight-forward application of the polynomial remainder theorem. I'm not sure this is the case for the inequality version.

Comment: Not sure I follow.  Take $x^2+1$.  The sum of the coefficients is $2$ which is certainly $>0$.  Yet there is no real root at all.

Comment: Consider $p(x)=x^2+x+1.$ Is there any root $r\ge 1?$

Comment: To be clear:  the claim about $1$ being a root  iff the sum of the coefficients is $0$ is trivial, since $p(1)=\sum a_n(1)^n=\sum a_n$.

Comment: I accidentally forgot to add a very important assumption, namely $a_n < 0$. Should I re-ask (since there's already an answer) or should I edit?

Comment: If you require $a_n<0$ then the claim is true, since $p(1)=\sum a_i>0$ but $\lim_{x\to \infty}p(x)=-\infty$.

Comment: @lulu Thanks. I was overthinking (because I was put on the remainder theorem track by one of the linked questions.)

Answer (score 3):

No, this is false. Take the polynomial $x^2+1$.

Comment: Somehow this is a complicated counter-example. $p(x)=x$ works as fine (not to mention $p(x)=1$).